# How to pass a parameter in routes to the controller?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to refactor my code. If I could pass an argument in the routes page to the controller where the function is, then I could refactor many of function that are almost identical.

Something like this in Router:

```
Route::get('/entrepreneurs', 'HomeController@show')->withParameter('enterpreneur');
```

Which gives me something like this in Controller:

```
public function entrepreneurs($withParameter){
   $entrepreneurs = DB::table('stars')->where('type', '=', $withParameter)->get();

   return view('entrepreneurs', [
     'entrepreneurs' => $entrepreneurs,
   ]);
 }
```

Is this possible?

-------- Update --------

Some of you are suggestion that I use Route Parameters:

```
Route::get('/entrepreneurs/{paramName}', 'HomeController@show');
```

However, I already use Route Model Binding to access individual pages (e.g. www.mywebsite.com/entrepreneurs/Mark_Zuckerberg)

So this is a conflicting with the solutions you guys provided!

Comment: I guess... *yes*. Can you please add more details to your question?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova....Sure, what would you like to know?

Comment: Does this parameter come in the request or is it a parameter that you define?

Comment: @JeanMarcos I define it beforehand, its static.

Comment: Pass it into the request and get the value in the controller

Comment: @stepbystep I have updated my answer.
If you are already using `/entrepreneur/{entrepreneurName}` and that you want to find entrepreneur list by type, you can specify another route like i did in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Routes:

```
Route::get('/entrepreneurs/{enterpreneur}', 'HomeController@show');
```

HomeController.php:

```
public function show($enterpreneur = "") 
{
   $entrepreneurs = DB::table('stars')->where('type', '=', $enterpreneur)->get();

   return view('entrepreneurs', [
     'entrepreneurs' => $entrepreneurs,
   ]);

}
```

To pass a static variable along with route

```
Route::get('/entrepreneurs', 'HomeController@show')->defaults('enterpreneur', 'value');
```

and access them in your controller as

```
public function show(Request $request) 
{
    $entrepreneur = $request->route('entrepreneur');
    $entrepreneurs = DB::table('stars')->where('type', '=', $enterpreneur)->get();

    return view('entrepreneurs', [
      'entrepreneurs' => $entrepreneurs,
    ]);

}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

// --------------- routes ---------------------

```
Route::get("page", [
    "uses" => 'HomeController@show',
    "entrepreneurs" => "value"
]);
```

// -------------- controller -------------------

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
    $entrepreneurs = DB::table('stars')->where('type', '=', $request->route()->getAction()["entrepreneurs"])->get();

    return view('entrepreneurs', [
        'entrepreneurs' => $entrepreneurs,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
Route::get('/entrepreneurs/{enterpreneur}', 'HomeController@show');

public function entrepreneurs($enterpreneur){
  $entrepreneurs = DB::table('stars')->where('type', '=', $enterpreneur)->get();

  return view('entrepreneurs', [
   'entrepreneurs' => $entrepreneurs,
  ]);
}
```

Hope this help for you !!!

Comment: How do I access {entrepreneur} in the controller? Just $entrepreneur?

Comment: @stepbystep Which type of conflicting?

Comment: I already use Route::get('/entrepreneurs/{entrepreneur}', 'StarsController@entrepreneursPage'); for pages like www.mysite.com/entrepreneurs/Mark_Zuckerberg. So I when I try to do what you recommend then for the same route two different controllers try run. Conflict.

Comment: @stepbystep So please change your route like Route::get('/entrepreneurs/show/{enterpreneur}', 'HomeController@show'); and try it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass param in your routes

```
Route::get('/entrepreneurs/type/{paramName}', 'HomeController@show');
```

And for an optionnal param :

```
Route::get('/entrepreneurs/type/{paramName?}', 'HomeController@show');
```

With optionnal paramater it should look like this in your controller :

```
public function show($paramName = null){
   $entrepreneurs = DB::table('stars')->where('type', '=', $paramName)->get();

   return view('entrepreneurs', [
     'entrepreneurs' => $entrepreneurs,
   ]);
 }
```

You can have more information here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-parameters